# Animate toolbar co-ordinator layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

When we scroll up the co ordinator layout for bottom to top, I need to scroll down the app top bar from top to few inchs down. I tried to animate the top bar but it animates only after the coodinator layout collapse completes. please suggest me how to animate this.

```
Toolbar toolbar_transtat_dash;
AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener offsetChanged = new 
AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {


    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {

        if (verticalOffset > -300) {
            toolbar_transtat_dash.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            opacity_change = ((float) Math.abs(verticalOffset) / appBarLayout_dash.getTotalScrollRange());
            toolbar_transtat_dash.setAlpha(opacity_change);
            toolbar_transtat_dash.setTranslationY(-toolbar_transtat_dash.getHeight());
            toolbar_transtat_dash.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(1500).start();

        }
    }

};
```